# Date conversion adding days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing the date conversion the following way:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, ZA2_DTFIM), 103) AS DATA
```

How can I add 5 days to that system date?

I tried several methods but so far nothing, I'm a beginner in SQL Server.

Comment: Why is this tagged `html`?

Comment: added tag "tsql" (and removed tag "html")

Comment: Aside: Bad habits to kick include using string data types without a length, e.g. `CONVERT(VARCHAR,...`. The default length is 30 in a `cast` or `convert`, otherwise 1. It's not worth saving a few keystrokes for something that will, sooner or later, get cut'n'pasted inappropriately and nibble thee.

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL the function [GETDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) provides the system date (and time).

To add 5 days to that use [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)(day,5,GETDATE())

To display this as a string you can use [FORMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or [CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) e.g. both of these will add 5 days to the system date and then display that in day/month/year style:

```
select
  convert(varchar,dateadd(day,5,getdate()),103)
, format(dateadd(day,5,getdate()),'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Note: you do not need to convert to date because converting (or formatting) GETDATE() to dd/MM/yyyy will suppress display of time anyway.